# (Computationally) Simple sigmoid

Tags: functions

I'm looking for the analytic expression of a computationally cheap sigmoid that passes through the points (0, 1) and (1, 0). Thoughts?

Comment: Is it okay if it's only defined on the interval $[0,1]$? If you want it to also be defined on all real axis, should it stay $0$ for inputs  $x>1$ and $1$ for negative inputs?

Comment: Ok just for [0, 1]; it really doesn't matter what happens outside that interval.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An extremely cheap option is the cubic spline with zero derivatives at both endpoints:
$$f(x)=1-3x^2+2x^3.$$
[image]

Comment: Rahul Narain, if I want to have even smoother curve at the endpoints, then I must use a higher order spline (5th, 7th etc), right? Is there another option, where I can have controllable smoothness (via parameter), which doesn't increase computational complexity with the increase of smoothness? (The second answer doesn't work for me, as I must strictly satisfy end point conditions).

Comment: You can try just using $f(x)=\dfrac{g(1-x)}{g(x)+g(1-x)}$ where $g(x)=\exp(-1/x)$, whose derivatives of all orders are zero at the endpoints.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I can also use $$g(x) = p^{-1/x}, p \ge 2$$ to control the shape.

Answer (score 3):

The [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is computationally cheap, and with a linear transform it can be adapted to $[0,1]$ interval: $\displaystyle \varsigma (x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(6\cdot(2x-1))}$ is shown here.
[image: logistic]

Strictly speaking, the curve misses both target points by $1/(1+e^6)\approx 0.002$. If this is a problem, tweak it:
$$\varsigma (x) = \frac{a}{1+\exp(6\cdot(2x-1))}-b \ \text{ where } 
a= \frac{1+\exp(-6)}{1-\exp(-6)}, \ b = \frac{1}{\exp(6)-1}$$
satisfies $\varsigma(0)=1$ and $\varsigma(1)=0$. Here $a\approx 1.005$ and $b\approx 0.0025$ are computed only once.

Of course, $6$ can be replaced by another number throughout the formulas.

Comment: Also, a [somewhat related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/297768/) was answered recently.

Comment: in bash: `sigmoid_a=$(echo "scale=10; (1+e(-6))/(1-e(-6))" | bc -l);
sigmoid_b=$(echo "scale=10; 1/(e(6)-1)" | bc -l);
sigmoid() {
    echo "scale=10; $sigmoid_a / (1+e(6*(2*$1 - 1))) - $sigmoid_b" | bc -l
}`