# Looking for code implementation of following exponential ramp function..

Tags: exponential-function, curves

I'm not a mathematician, but a software developer.  So I am much more comfortable reading code than I am math notation.

Could someone help provide some code for the following:

[How would I create a exponential ramp function from 0,0 to 1,1 with a single value to explain curvature?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297768/how-would-i-create-a-exponential-ramp-function-from-0-0-to-1-1-with-a-single-val?newreg=667d44b6cfca438d853d5ead26d0516f)

I don't mind which language (but would prefer C# or javascript), and would certainly prefer the usage of built in math functions.

Looking for an implementation of

---

// x is a value between 0 and 1.

// y is a value between 0 and 1.

float GetY(float x, float curvature)

---

Any guidance would be much appreciated,
Regards,
Daniel.

Comment: Here is an R version of such a function: myramp = function(x,curvature){y = x; if (curvature != 0) {y = (exp(curvature*x)-1)/(exp(curvature)-1)}; return(y}}. .

Comment: thankyou for taking the time to answer this.  This has been a great help.  I have created the following for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/6464/ With a curvature argument of 0.5, shouldn't the line be perfectly linear?  It doesn't seem like it is.