# (Computationally) Simple sigmoid with specific slopes at specific points

Tags: functions

This is a refinement of this question: [(Computationally) Simple sigmoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290768/computationally-simple-sigmoid).

Ideally, I would like to have relatively simple sigmoid function with the following properties:

1. derivatives at -1 and 1 are zero
2. derivative is not zero between -1 and 1
3. derivative at 0 is 1, maybe can be controlled with a parameter
4. I can control the change in derivative near -1 and 1 within (-1,1), so that the derivative doesn't depart from zero too quickly or too slowly.
5. The curve is "symmetric" in the sense that flipping the curve on [0,1] both vertically and horizontally produces the curve on [0,1].

Approximations to items 1 through 5 are OK.  This is for a computer simulation in which values $c$ in [-1,1] cause an increase or decrease in other values $e$ in [-1,1].  I want $e$ to change quickly when it's pushed around in the middle range near 0, but to be pushed up slowly when it's near 1, and similarly when pushed down near -1.  I just need a function that works well enough; it doesn't have to perfect.

I've had trouble figuring out how to tune the sigmoids I'm aware of in order to get properties that are close to 1 through 5.

Thanks!

Comment: One possible solution is $\tanh(\frac{-kx}{x^2-1})$ for positive k.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks @Belov. The slope approaches 0 a little too far from -1 and 1 for my taste, but I can make the approach softer by multiplying $x^2$ by a constant, even if that means it's not really flat at -1 and 1.  You should put this into an answer and get credit.

Comment: Did and made some explanation how to get some more if you need.

Comment: Will your sigmoid be dealing with arguments outside $[-1,1]$?

Comment: No, just that interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a possible solution is $$\tanh\frac{kx}{(1-x^2)^{1/n}}$$
For $k > 0, n \geq 1$ being a constants for adjustment of the function as you like.
In general to explain how you can construct more sigmoid functions.
Let's assume we have a sigmoid function $f(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow[-1;1]$ and we want to make it to find $g(x): [-1;1] \rightarrow[-1;1]$ what we can do is use a mapping $h(x):[-1;1] \rightarrow [-\infty ; \infty]$ and define $g(x) = f(h(x))$. Such mapping is $h(x) = \frac{kx}{(1-x^2)^{1/n}}$. Using this you can build and more functions for what you need using different well known sigmoids. And you should play a bit with $k$ and $n$ to find a good solution.
And don't forget that for any sigmoid $f(x):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0;1]$ you can transform them to $[-1;1]$ by taking $2*f(x)-1$ and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks very much for the additional parameter `n`, the additional explanation!

Comment: Belov, btw I'm now finding your function useful with $n\in (0,1)$ as well as $\geq 1$.  Recently I needed a function that's flat near 0 and then steeply rises/drops to extreme values near 1 and -1, and your function allows that with small $n$ (e.g. $k=0.01$, $n=0.35$).  I'm not sure whether it counts as a sigmoid any more--certainly not a paradigmatic sigmoid, I guess.  (For some reason I neglected to upvote as well as accept your answer two years ago--now corrected.)